# Is my Idea possible in VB.Net ? If no which lang should I take

Tags: vb.net, email, usb

I have a nice Idea in my head.
Im thinking about writing an application in VB.Net, that can control USB ports.
The purpose will look like:
Im at home, I wannt a ready hot coffee as Im in my office. So i take my phone and I write a mail to adres (example) IWanntMyCoffe@gmail.com. The body of the mail is "DO_A_Coffee"
The application, running on my laptop in the office gets the mail.
It recognizes the string "DO_A_COFFEE" and uses the usb port to activate the prepared Machine to make my coffee.

I know that VB.NET has a tool for USB connections, but I have no experience with that. 
But at all, is this even possible in vb.net?

Comment: You have a coffee machine with an usb port to be controlled by your pc?

Comment: No, i have a knowledge with electronics, I could do it the way, as electricity comes from the usb port it closes the circulation and the machine would run

Comment: Would it not be much easier to usb->serial, and send something to the serial port (or even use a existing serial port on your pc)? Talking to the serial port is definitly possible from within .net languages.

Comment: Alright, can you make an example of sending signals to the port using .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found with Google (VB.NET Serial port)

```
Sub SendSerialData(ByVal data As String)
    ' Send strings to a serial port.
    Using com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = 
            My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM1")
        com1.WriteLine(data)
    End Using
End Sub
```